# MemoryStream in SQL CLR to SQL

Tags: c#, stream, clr, sql-server-2014, sqlclr

In my CLR code i have a memorystream which contains xml. I would like to pass this xml back to my SQL which invoked the CLR.  Just wanted to see if you guys can give me some suggestions of how best to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

I am using 
.Net 4.6
C# for the CLR
SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the memory stream in a new SqlXml class:

```
[SqlFunction(Name = "ReturnXml")]
public static SqlXml ReturnXml()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    // fill your memory stream
    return new SqlXml(ms);
}
```